# Logstash: how to get field from path when using Filebeat?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

The necessary part of the Filebeat config:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - C:\Program Files\Filebeat\test_logs\*.txt
```

After sending to logstash and elasticsearch, the following field appears:

```
"log": {
          "offset": 117,
           "file": {
                "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\\test_logs\\20200804_0929_logui.txt"
  }
```

I would like to get the folder name / file name as separate fields, but don't know how.

Already tried something like this:

```
grok {
    match => { 'path' => '(C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\\test_logs\\)%{GREEDYDATA:filename}\.txt' }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work.

Please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the [`dissect` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html), much easier:

```
  filter {
    dissect {
      mapping => {
        "[log][file][path]" => "C:\\Program Files\\Filebeat\\test_logs\\%{[log][file][name]}.txt"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is a good way for paths, but I need to get this path from somewhere. The path is not contained within the logs, it comes from Filebeat and is then put into the log field. How can I refer to this field to get what I need from it (using Dissect)?

Comment: I've updated my answer, instead of checking the `message` field, dissect needs to check the `log.file.path` field